# What caused my CentOS 6.4 box to reboot itself?

Tags: centos, mysql, reboot

I noticed that the MySQL daemon running on my CentOS 6.4 machine was suddenly not running anymore. I checked the MySQL log, but didn't see anything relevant:

```
121229 22:17:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
121229 22:17:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
121229 22:17:50  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
121229 22:17:50  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121229 22:17:50  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 206087326
121229 22:17:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121229 22:17:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.66-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130205 11:09:32 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130205 11:09:32 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130205 11:09:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130205 11:09:36  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 529664030
130205 11:09:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130205 11:09:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130205 11:09:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130205 11:09:37  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130205 11:09:37  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130205 11:09:37  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 529664030
130205 11:09:37 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130205 11:09:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.67-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130310 11:33:12 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130310 11:33:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130310 11:33:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130310 11:33:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 788753738
130310 11:33:16 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130310 11:33:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130310 11:36:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130310 11:36:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130310 11:36:03  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130310 11:36:04  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 788753738
130310 11:36:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130310 11:36:04 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.67-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130413 20:56:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130413 20:56:56  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130413 20:56:56  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 1139894636
130413 20:56:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 1139895853
130413 20:56:56  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 335782050, file name ./mysql-bin.000003
130413 20:56:57  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1139895853
130413 20:56:57 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
130413 20:56:59 [ERROR] Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'read error', data_len: 809, event_type: 2
130413 20:56:59 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130413 20:56:59 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130413 20:56:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130413 20:56:59 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.67-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Then I checked `/var/log/messages`, and realized the system was rebooted for some reason:

```
Apr  7 03:48:03 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1335" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1370" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Linux version 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 13 00:26:49 UTC 2013
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  Intel GenuineIntel
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  AMD AuthenticAMD
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  Centaur CentaurHauls
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009b000 (usable)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000000009b000 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000008bf64000 (usable)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008bf64000 - 000000008c051000 (ACPI NVS)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008c051000 - 000000008c13d000 (ACPI data)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008c13d000 - 000000008d53d000 (ACPI NVS)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008d53d000 - 000000008f602000 (ACPI data)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f602000 - 000000008f64f000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f64f000 - 000000008f6e4000 (ACPI data)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f6e4000 - 000000008f6ef000 (ACPI NVS)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f6ef000 - 000000008f6f1000 (ACPI data)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f6f1000 - 000000008f7cf000 (ACPI NVS)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f7cf000 - 000000008f800000 (ACPI data)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000008f800000 - 0000000090000000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000a0000000 - 00000000b0000000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fc000000 - 00000000fd000000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fed1c000 - 00000000fed20000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000ff800000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000270000000 (usable)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: DMI 2.5 present.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: SMBIOS version 2.5 @ 0xF0440
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: last_pfn = 0x270000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: last_pfn = 0x8bf64 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Using GB pages for direct mapping
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-000000008bf64000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-0000000270000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: RAMDISK: 3717b000 - 37fef73a
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f0410 00024 (v02 Cisco0)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: XSDT 000000008f7fe120 0009C (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000000      01000013)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: FACP 000000008f7fc000 000F4 (v04 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000000 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: DSDT 000000008f7f6000 05DBE (v02 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000003 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: FACS 000000008f6f1000 00040
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: APIC 000000008f7f5000 001A8 (v02 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000000 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: MCFG 000000008f7f4000 0003C (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000001 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: HPET 000000008f7f3000 00038 (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000001 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: SLIT 000000008f7f2000 00030 (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000001 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: SPCR 000000008f7f1000 00050 (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000000 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: WDDT 000000008f7f0000 00040 (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000000 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: SSDT 000000008f7d5000 1AFC4 (v02  Cisco SSDT  PM 00004000 INTL 20090730)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: SSDT 000000008f7d4000 001D8 (v02  Cisco IPMI     00004000 INTL 20090730)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: SSDT 000000008f7d3000 00962 (v02 CISCO  PMETER   00004000 INTL 20090730)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: HEST 000000008f7d1000 000A8 (v01 Cisco  CiscoTbl 00000001 CISC 00000001)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: BERT 000000008f7d0000 00030 (v01 Cisco  CiscoTbl 00000001 CISC 00000001)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: ERST 000000008f7cf000 00230 (v01 Cisco  CiscoTbl 00000001 CISC 00000001)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: EINJ 000000008f6f0000 00130 (v01 Cisco  CiscoTbl 00000001 CISC 00000001)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: DMAR 000000008f6ef000 001A8 (v01 Cisco0 CiscoUCS 00000001 MSFT 0100000D)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Setting APIC routing to flat.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: No NUMA configuration found
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Faking a node at 0000000000000000-0000000270000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-0000000270000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  NODE_DATA [000000000000b000 - 000000000003efff]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  bootmap [000000000003f000 -  000000000008cfff] pages 4e
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: (9 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 0270000000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #1 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #2 [0001000000 - 000201b0a4]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 000201b0a4]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #3 [003717b000 - 0037fef73a]          RAMDISK ==> [003717b000 - 0037fef73a]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #4 [000009b000 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009b000 - 0000100000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #5 [000201c000 - 000201c2f8]              BRK ==> [000201c000 - 000201c2f8]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #6 [0000008000 - 000000a000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000008000 - 000000a000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #7 [000000a000 - 000000b000]          PGTABLE ==> [000000a000 - 000000b000]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  #8 [0000001000 - 0000001030]        ACPI SLIT ==> [0000001000 - 0000001030]
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fc640] fc640
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Reserving 129MB of memory at 48MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 9984MB)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Zone PFN ranges:
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  DMA      0x00000001 -> 0x00001000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:  Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x00270000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Movable zone start PFN for each node
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: early_node_map[3] active PFN ranges
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00000001 -> 0x0000009b
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00000100 -> 0x0008bf64
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00100000 -> 0x00270000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Setting APIC routing to flat.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x12] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x14] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x13] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x15] enabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x09] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0a] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0b] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0c] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0d] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0e] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0f] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x10] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x11] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x12] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x13] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x14] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x15] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x16] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x17] lapic_id[0xff] disabled)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x05] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x06] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x07] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x08] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x09] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0a] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0b] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0c] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0d] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0e] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0f] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x10] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x11] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x12] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x13] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x14] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x15] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x16] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x17] high level lint[0x1])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x08] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 8, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x09] address[0xfec90000] gsi_base[24])
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 9, version 32, address 0xfec90000, GSI 24-47
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a401 base: 0xfed00000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: SMP: Allowing 24 CPUs, 16 hotplug CPUs
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009b000 - 00000000000a0000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000e0000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008bf64000 - 000000008c051000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008c051000 - 000000008c13d000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008c13d000 - 000000008d53d000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008d53d000 - 000000008f602000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f602000 - 000000008f64f000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f64f000 - 000000008f6e4000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f6e4000 - 000000008f6ef000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f6ef000 - 000000008f6f1000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f6f1000 - 000000008f7cf000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f7cf000 - 000000008f800000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000008f800000 - 0000000090000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 0000000090000000 - 00000000a0000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000a0000000 - 00000000b0000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000b0000000 - 00000000fc000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fc000000 - 00000000fd000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fd000000 - 00000000fed1c000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed1c000 - 00000000fed20000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed20000 - 00000000ff800000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000ff800000 - 0000000100000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Allocating PCI resources starting at b0000000 (gap: b0000000:4c000000)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: NR_CPUS:4096 nr_cpumask_bits:24 nr_cpu_ids:24 nr_node_ids:1
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PERCPU: Embedded 31 pages/cpu @ffff88002f800000 s94552 r8192 d24232 u131072
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: pcpu-alloc: s94552 r8192 d24232 u131072 alloc=1*2097152
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: pcpu-alloc: [0] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: pcpu-alloc: [0] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2045459
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Policy zone: Normal
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=129M@0M rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Checking aperture...
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: No AGP bridge found
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Placing 64MB software IO TLB between ffff880020000000 - ffff880024000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: software IO TLB at phys 0x20000000 - 0x24000000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Memory: 7972340k/10223616k available (5221k kernel code, 1901576k absent, 349700k reserved, 7121k data, 1264k init)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:1008
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Extended CMOS year: 2000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: console [tty0] enabled
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: allocated 33554432 bytes of page_cgroup
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Detected 2666.901 MHz processor.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 5333.80 BogoMIPS (lpj=2666901)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Security Framework initialized
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: SELinux:  Initializing.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: mce: CPU supports 9 MCE banks
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: using mwait in idle threads.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: Core revision 20090903
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ftrace: converting mcount calls to 0f 1f 44 00 00
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ftrace: allocating 21430 entries in 85 pages
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: Host address width 40
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: DRHD base: 0x000000fe710000 flags: 0x1
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: IOMMU 0: reg_base_addr fe710000 ver 1:0 cap c90780106f0462 ecap f020fe
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f62f000 end: 0x0000008f631fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f61a000 end: 0x0000008f61afff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f617000 end: 0x0000008f617fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f614000 end: 0x0000008f614fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f611000 end: 0x0000008f611fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f60e000 end: 0x0000008f60efff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f60b000 end: 0x0000008f60bfff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f608000 end: 0x0000008f608fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: RMRR base: 0x0000008f605000 end: 0x0000008f605fff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: dmar: No ATSR found
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base 0xfe710000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: IOAPIC id 9 under DRHD base 0xfe710000
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Enabled IRQ remapping in xapic mode
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Setting APIC routing to physical flat
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5640  @ 2.67GHz stepping 02
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Performance Events: PEBS fmt1+, Westmere events, Intel PMU driver.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: CPUID marked event: 'bus cycles' unavailable
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... version:                3
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... bit width:              48
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... generic registers:      4
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... max period:             000000007fffffff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... fixed-purpose events:   3
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ... event mask:             000000070000000f
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Booting Node   0, Processors  #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Brought up 8 CPUs
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: Total of 8 processors activated (42670.41 BogoMIPS).
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: devtmpfs: initialized
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 8bf64000 (970752 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 8c13d000 (20971520 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 8f6e4000 (45056 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 8f6f1000 (909312 bytes)
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: regulator: core version 0.5
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 16
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: bus type pci registered
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PCI: MCFG configuration 0: base a0000000 segment 0 buses 0 - 255
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PCI: MCFG area at a0000000 reserved in E820
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PCI: Using MMCONFIG at a0000000 - afffffff
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: Interpreter enabled
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: ACPI: (supports S0 S5)
```

How can I determine what caused the system to be rebooted?

Comment: Need logs from pre boot to see if there's anything logged on why it rebooted.

Comment: @John let check but there is limitation on how many lines I can post any other alternative where I can send you maybe by email?

Comment: Look through /var/log/messages and look at the entries before the boot and see if you notice any crash related messages or if syslog received a signal 15.  You can also look through the last logs by running "last" to see the time period when the system rebooted to narrow down the time in the log.  Is this a server, multi-users on it, multiple with root?  or is this a desktop?

Comment: It is a pure server. Unfortunately I tried to go back just found this Apr  7 03:48:03 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1335" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Apr 13 17:19:07 localhost kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started. That is all I found.

Comment: Not a lot to go by.  That's just saying rsyslogd was restarted with a HUP signal.  If there's no other messages of any kind to help it's very hard to figure out a "why?".

Comment: @What is a hup signal and where and which else logs must I look into I cant find any syslog in /var/log? Where to look ?

Comment: If this is a Red Hat based distro then syslog logs to /var/log/messages, other distro's sometimes log there and sometimes to /var/log/syslog.  A HUP is a restart signal.  There's probably something else in messages somewhere.  Check last and see if it shows a reboot and check your uptime to see how long the server has been up.  Was there a power blip?  I've had boxes magically reboot and then I find out there was a short power outage over night and the box was set to auto boot on power out.  Course these are home boxes.

Comment: Yes this is a centos 6.4 machine. Ok what I did recently I rebooted  myself to the uptime is since I rebooted few days ago. There are few servers there so if there is a power trip then all of it should be effected. Where else to look out any idea ?

Comment: @John here is my last statement before and after that reboot reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.2.1.e Sat Apr 13 17:19 - 12:47 This is the list root     pts/0        10.212.134.200   Sat Apr 13 21:21 - 21:40  (00:18)
root     pts/0        10.212.134.200   Sat Apr 13 20:56 - 20:59  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.2.1.e Sat Apr 13 17:19 - 12:47 (3+19:28)
root     pts/0        121.121.12.249   Sat Mar 16 12:31 - 12:41  (00:10)
root     pts/0        10.212.134.200   Sun Mar 10 11:35 - 11:40  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.0.1.e Sun Mar 10 11:35 - 12:47 (38+01:12)

Comment: Please check your HDD space. I thing it is full used.

Answer (score 1):

When Linux crashes, it crashes hard and rarely leaves behind a usable kernel core that gives you any help. For such a system, there's a few things you should do:

1. Step up syslog output. Your system using rsyslogd which is even better. Ultimately you have a rule such as:

   ```
   *.* /var/log/debug
   ```

   Make sure the kernel module is enabled in rsyslogd. I've seen some installations comment it out. It's

   ```
   $modLoad imklog
   ```

   Make sure you rotate that file every day. You need to only save 2 rotations. In /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

   ```
   /var/log/debug
   {
     compress
     daily
     rotate 2
     sharedscripts
     postrotate
       /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
     endscript
   }
   ```

   I also like to enable the `mark` facility to output every 5 minutes, but that's more useful in a network and when you're not doing any other monitoring.
2. I have a script which I created to capture the ps table. It runs every minute via cron. It's great at being able to identify which processes have memory leaks and the like. The command I use for this is more or less:

   ```
   /bin/ps -A --sort tty,comm,pid -ww -o pgrp:8,tty:7,pid,c,pmem:5,rss:8,sz:8,size:8=TSIZE,vsz:8,nlwp,lstart,args
   ```

   I have that piped inside a perl-script which removes the "dead-weight" output such as user shells and kernel threads. Comment if interested in the full script. The files can grow up to 12 MB per day, but daily compression reduces that to a few hundred kB.
3. I consider use of the `sysstat` package essential. Here is how mine is often configured (`/etc/cron.d/sysstat`)

   ```
   */10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 10 60
   58  23 * * * root rm -f /var/lib/sa/sa$(date +%d --date=tomorrow)
   ```

   That's capturing system data every 10 seconds for 10 minutes at a time. Feel free to lower that on a heavily-loaded system. Also be aware *this takes a lot of disk space*. To prevent corruption in the sar file, tomorrow's sar file from last month is removed shortly before midnight. (However, if the month ends on day 30, then day 31 of last month will still remain. *shrug*)

Throw these three things on your system, and if you're unlucky again, you'll have LOTS of data at your disposal. Maybe some of it might be useful.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this adds a bit of load to the box and best to use it only for troubleshooting? I am just curious and I am trying to learn. Hope this comment is not inappropriate. I am not the Original Poster.

Comment: `sa` is very very efficient. 

The `ps` command is a little heavier. Writing its output to disk is probably the heaviest operation on modern CPUs. 

Using `cron` is probably the most resource-intensive of all. But it's the easiest to do without more involved scripting.

Still, given the tons of resource-heavy management crap on modern environments (puppet, osad, dbus), you will notice nothing unless you are on an embedded environment running on an ARM chip or something.

Answer (score 0):

At this point it looks like you've exhausted all definitive sources for the answer to this question. I'd say your best bet now would be to try and reproduce the problem. This approach isn't going to ever tell you for certain what happened but it will verify whether you still have good hardware (which is more important than the WHY anyway). I'd run a full memory test and drive test at a minimum.

Here is a good test script which not only tests your memory but also your hardwares DMA access (which is just as likely to be the problem): http://people.redhat.com/dledford/memtest.shtml

I'd definitely also check your hard drive for errors; even the video & sound hardware could use a test just to be sure.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this issue caused by hardware failure. Every time I've seen it, it's been a kernel panic, or power outage. Not saying it doesn't happen, but it's not as common as people think.